# Why does JavaSystem.LoadLibrary() throw an UnsatisfiedLinkError despite the library existing in project?

Tags: c#, android, dependencies, maui, .so

I try to embedd an external library to my .Net MAUI project, but am unable to.

Following the process in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73500511/how-to-include-existing-c-libraries-per-platform-in-maui-project) question:

- I copied the `.so` file into
  `<project root>\Resources\lib\<platform>\` (the platforms being `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86_64`).
- Then set the `Build Action = AndroidNativeLibrary` for the file
- I set the `<AndroidNativeLibrary Include="Resources\lib\<platform>" />` in my `.csproj` file
- Then I call `JavaSystem.LoadLibrary(lib name);` in the `MainActivity.cs` file of the Android project (which is my target platform)

As soon as my App is starting I receive a `Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkgError: 'dlopen failed: library libc++_shared.so" not found'`

**Why do I get this Error?** My interpretation is, that the path to my library is wrong or the file is not correctly included into the build process, but I don't know why my previous steps are not sufficient.

I already tried to solve this by:

- moving the path of the `.so` file into the platform specific folders `\Platforms\Android\lib\<platform>`
- changing the `<CopyToOutputDirectory></CopyToOutputDirectory>` to various options

Unfortunately without success.

*Edit: Fixing a typo*

Comment: Did you try to just keep the arm64-v8a and delete the rest two platforms? Just like the answer you mentioned in the link did.